# Mysql: Insert into JSON column type with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, json

I'm trying to insert a list of words into a column with the `JSON` type:

```sql
create table my_table (
    ...
    synonyms JSON
    ...
)
```

My query looks like this:

```sql
INSERT into my_table (id, synonyms)
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT synonyms) as synonyms from (
  SELECT id, name1,name2, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name1) as synonyms
  FROM products
  GROUP BY id

  UNION

  SELECT id, name1,name2, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT name2) as synonyms
  FROM products
  GROUP BY id
) t group by id;
```

If run without the INSERT in line one, the `synonyms` column returns a list of comma separated words:

```
id       name1    name2    synonyms
------------------------------------
1        one      a,b      one,a,b
2        two      c        two,c
```

I want to insert those synonyms as a JSON_ARRAY.  However, the INSERT fails when the individual words are not double quoted.  If I add JSON_ARRAY in my select:

```sql
SELECT name1,name2,id, JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT synonyms)) ...
```

I get the following result:

```
name1    name2    synonyms
----------------------------
one      a,b      ["one,a,b"]
two      c        ["two,c"]
```

When what I want is this (so it can be inserted directly into the `synonyms` column):

```
name1    name2    synonyms
----------------------------
one      a,b      ["one","a","b"]
two      c        ["two","c"]
```

Is there a way to do this with SQL, or is it better handled within application code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) instead of `GROUP_CONCAT()`. - [akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina)

It is available only in 5.7.22+

Does it have an implicit `DISTINCT`? I don't know...if not, subquery with `DISTINCT` will help.

Comment: It doesn't look like it does an implicit distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `concat` inside the `group_concat` to achieve this, like in this sample:

```
SELECT name1, name2, id, 
       CONCAT(
          '[',
          GROUP_CONCAT(
             CONCAT(
                '"',
                synonyms,
                '"'
             )
          ),
          ']'
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

Query like this

```sql
SELECT 
   campaign_id, 
   CAST( CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(id),']') AS JSON ) AS posts 
FROM 
  posts
WHERE 
     campaign_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY campaign_id
```

will return

| campaign_id | posts |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | [1005, 1006, 1007] |
| 5 | [1002, 1003, 1004] |